# Products Name are not updating through csv file in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel

I am using magento 1.9.2. I want to update some product's name, description and short_description attributes. I have made a CSV file and updated by admin panel. It it showing  successfully updated and it have been updated description and short_description but product name are not updating. Please anyone give me a solution.

Comment: which method you use to update product???

Comment: I am updating by admin panel System>>Import/Export>>Import and I have set Import Behavior ==Replace Existing Complex Data. After this I have checked csv valid or not the after showing valid csv message I have imported.

Answer (score 0):

As per the scenario, I think product names are stored in store specific.

Edit any of the product for which you want to change the name in the admin panel.
change the store view and check against name filed is there any value set against it.

Comment: I am trying to change Product name but it is not getting change

Answer (score 0):

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
$p->setName("Name of product");
$p->save();
```